# Outlook VBA - Email from excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have created the below code but I am unable to call the signature. I am looking for call the mail before so that I can get the default signature or if anyone can suggest a workaround. I am new to VBA and i am unable to find a solution. Thank you in advance

```
Sub Email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody, SigString, signature As String
Dim MailAttachments As String
Dim cell As Variant                                 'Not previously DIM'd
Dim GetBoiler As Object

Sheets("List").Select                               'Edit as required
Range("A2").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
        LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "yes" Then

        With Application.ActiveSheet
            MailAttachments = Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value
        End With
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail

                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Monthly Review Meeting with Professional Direct Support for Microsoft Azure – " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value  'Refer value from column A (company name)
                .HTMLBody = "" & _
                "<style> body{color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size: 11pt;}" & "<HTML><body>" & "<p>" & "Hello " & Cells(cell.Row, "B") & ", " & "<br>" & "</br>" & "<br>" & "I am the delivery manager associated to " & "<b>" & Cells(cell.Row, "A") & "</b>" & "<br>" & "</br>" _
                '.Attachments.Add MailAttachments
                .Display
                'Or use .Send

            End With
                SigString = Environ("appdata") & " Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\Sign.htm"
                If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
                    signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
                Else
                    signature = ""

                End If

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
            Set OutApp = Nothing

    End If
Next
cleanup:
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
End Function`
```

Comment: FYI `Dim strbody, SigString, signature As String` is declaring `signature` as a `String`, and both `strbody` and `SigString` are implicit `Variant`. All variables need an explicit type. So declare them on separate `Dim` instructions, or do `Dim strbody As String, SigString As String, signature As String`. Also `cell` should be `As Range`.

Comment: Do you get any actual errors if you remove `On Error Resume Next`? FWIW OERN is usually the worst way to deal with run-time errors; it hides the real problem and makes bugs MUCH harder to find.

Comment: Can I also recommend you rethink `For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells` - that is processing 1,048,576 cells (assuming you are using a version of Excel more recent than 2003), so consider using something like `For Each cell In Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells` or `For Each cell In Intersect(Columns("C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells`.

Comment: In your `Email` procedure, you are declaring a variable `Dim GetBoiler As Object`.  Later you have a statement saying `signature = GetBoiler(SigString)` which is making use of that object.  But nowhere do you create the object.  I suspect you intended to make use of the `GetBoiler` procedure at the bottom of your posted code so, if that is the intention, delete the `Dim GetBoiler As Object` which is preventing you from accessing the function.  (People would have noticed that earlier if you included within your question any error messages you are getting and on which lines the errors occur.)

Comment: Ahhh - I apologise - @Mat'sMug mentioned you have an OERN to mask that error, so I assume that means you are happy for that `signature = GetBoiler(SigString)` line to not work.

Comment: A bug in [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) ???  Sack the project manager!!

Comment: @YowE3K lol, it's the angle brackets, html-decoding the input form messes it up - doesn't happen in the actual VBE ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yeah, yeah, blame it on the browser interface.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good so far. However let me propose an easier way to get a signature. When someone opens a new e-mail, the signature is displayed by default. So if we force the e-mail to display, we can then save the html body (with the signature included) for later inserting

```
.With OutMail  
.Display   
t = .HTMLBody
```

Then for when you want to edit your .HTMLBody you would put something like

```
.HTMLBody = "something something blah blah" & "<br/>" & t
```